# Verificar si un registro existe en sql server y c#

Tags: c#, sql

Buen día,

Quiero saber la diferencia entre usar un reader sin WHILE y con WHILE, ya que este tema me confunde mucho, por ejemplo, tengo el siguiente codigo que me indica si un usuario ya existe en la tabla, esto funciona bien si lo hago solo con el reader(), pero si ejecuto el reader con el while, el msgbox se repite muchas veces.

En resumen? Cuando se debe utilizar el reader solo, y cuando se debe usar el while para recuperar datos?

```
     cls_general myCls_general = new cls_general();

            myCls_general.conexion_mssql("1");

            mysqlcommand_select.Connection = myCls_general.myConnection;

            strSQL = " SELECT usuario_remitente_id " +
                     " FROM  EnviosRemitentes " +
                     " WHERE usuario_remitente_id='" + remitente + "'";

            mysqlcommand_select.CommandText = strSQL;

            mySqlDatareader_select = mysqlcommand_select.ExecuteReader();

            try
            {

                if (mySqlDatareader_select.HasRows)
                {
                    mySqlDatareader_select.Read();

                    if (dgv_list_controladores.RowCount > 0)
                    {

                        for (int i = 0; i < dgv_list_controladores.DataRowCount; i++)
                        {

                            if (dgv_list_controladores.GetRowCellValue(i, "usuario_remitente_id").ToString() == remitente)
                            {

                                cls_MessageBox mensaje = new cls_MessageBox("8");
                                XtraMessageBox.Show(mensaje).ToString();

                                //Si el contacto ya está referenciado, se limpian los campos para seleccionar otro.
                                limpiar_campos_remitentes();


                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                FlyoutMessageBox.Show("Se ha detectado una situación inesperada, comunicate con el administrador del sistema: error en la función consultar remitente.", "SISTEMA", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
            }
            finally
            {
                mySqlDatareader_select.Close();
                myCls_general.cerrar_conexion();
            }
```

CON WHILE

```
     cls_general myCls_general = new cls_general();

            myCls_general.conexion_mssql("1");

            mysqlcommand_select.Connection = myCls_general.myConnection;

            strSQL = " SELECT usuario_remitente_id " +
                     " FROM  EnviosRemitentes " +
                     " WHERE usuario_remitente_id='" + remitente + "'";

            mysqlcommand_select.CommandText = strSQL;

            mySqlDatareader_select = mysqlcommand_select.ExecuteReader();

            try
            {

                if (mySqlDatareader_select.HasRows)
                {
                   while(mySqlDatareader_select.Read())
{

                    if (dgv_list_controladores.RowCount > 0)
                    {

                        for (int i = 0; i < dgv_list_controladores.DataRowCount; i++)
                        {

                            if (dgv_list_controladores.GetRowCellValue(i, "usuario_remitente_id").ToString() == remitente)
                            {

                                cls_MessageBox mensaje = new cls_MessageBox("8");
                                XtraMessageBox.Show(mensaje).ToString();

                                //Si el contacto ya está referenciado, se limpian los campos para seleccionar otro.
                                limpiar_campos_remitentes();

 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
              }
            }
            catch
            {
                FlyoutMessageBox.Show("Se ha detectado una situación inesperada, comunicate con el administrador del sistema: error en la función consultar remitente.", "SISTEMA", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
            }
            finally
            {
                mySqlDatareader_select.Close();
                myCls_general.cerrar_conexion();
            }
```

Quiero aprender la forma correcta de usar un reader(). Tambien se que el SQL se presta a inyección y que la consulta debe ser parametrizada, pero es solo una prueba, primero me es de interes saber como usar bien la consulta.

Answer (score 2):

Lo correcto es siempre usar el while y si lo correcto es siempre parametizar la consulta. Hay un detalle  en este caso paticular y es que le esta sirviendo la busqueda sin el while porque  esta utilizando un "DataRowCount" y si no me equivoco eso no es propiamente del namespace System.Data.SqlClient. Me parece que eso es algo propio de DevExpress , Telerik o alguno de esos y por eso le funciona así. Pero si esto fuera con el namespace de System.Data.SqlClient su código sería diferente porque ni el "DataRowCount" ni el "GetRowCellValue" le servirían. Su confusión posiblemente sea porque esta usando cosas que no son oficiales del namespace de microsoft sino que esta utilizando librerías de terceros como devexpress o el que sea que este usando.  Y por otro lado  la razón por la que le imprime varias veces el mensaje es porque el mensaje no esta en el lugar donde debería ir. Lo que se puede hacer es crear una variable que indique si el usuario existe o no luego de haber recorrido todos los registros de la siguiente manera:

```
 cls_general myCls_general = new cls_general();

    myCls_general.conexion_mssql("1");

    mysqlcommand_select.Connection = myCls_general.myConnection;

    strSQL = " SELECT usuario_remitente_id " +
             " FROM  EnviosRemitentes " +
             " WHERE usuario_remitente_id='" + remitente + "'";

    mysqlcommand_select.CommandText = strSQL;

    mySqlDatareader_select = mysqlcommand_select.ExecuteReader();

    bool existe = false;
    try
    {

        if (mySqlDatareader_select.HasRows)
        {
            while (mySqlDatareader_select.Read())
            {

                if (dgv_list_controladores.RowCount > 0)
                {

                    for (int i = 0; i < dgv_list_controladores.DataRowCount; i++)
                    {

                        if (dgv_list_controladores.GetRowCellValue(i, "usuario_remitente_id").ToString() == remitente)
                        {

                            existe = true;


                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        if (existe)
        {
            cls_MessageBox mensaje = new cls_MessageBox("8");
            XtraMessageBox.Show(mensaje).ToString();

            //Si el contacto ya está referenciado, se limpian los campos para seleccionar otro.
            limpiar_campos_remitentes();
        }
        else{
           //mensaje de que no existe o lo que corresponda
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        FlyoutMessageBox.Show("Se ha detectado una situación inesperada, comunicate con el administrador del sistema: error en la función consultar remitente.", "SISTEMA", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
    }
    finally
    {
        mySqlDatareader_select.Close();
        myCls_general.cerrar_conexion();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Usar el `while` aplica cuando esperas mas de un registro como respuesta de la consulta iterando cada uno

```
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            
while(reader.Read())
{
    //codigo
}
```

si solo esperas uno solo registro entonces usas el `if`

```
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            
if(reader.Read())
{
    //codigo
}
```

**>>se que el SQL se presta a inyección y que la consulta debe ser parametrizada, pero es solo una prueba**

si sabes que algo esta mal y conoces la forma correcta sea o no una prueba deberias hacerlo bien, no atado con alambre

```
cls_general myCls_general = new cls_general();
myCls_general.conexion_mssql("1");

string strSQL = @"SELECT usuario_remitente_id 
                  FROM  EnviosRemitentes 
                  WHERE usuario_remitente_id= ?remitente";

var cmd = new MySqlCommand(strSQL, myCls_general.myConnection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?remitente", remitente);
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            
if(reader.Read())
{
    //codigo
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. Por ultimo, si solo regresa un solo registro y tiene el WHILE aplicado, afecta en algo?

Comment: Te puedo consultar porque en el parametro no usas @ y si "?", que diferencia tienen? Otra duda, se puede parametrizar un select, insert, update, delete... sin necesidad de pasarle el tipo de campo? Veo que en tu codigo, no defines el tipo de campo que tiene el diseño de la base de datos.

Comment: si solo retorna un registro y usas el while solo lo itera una unica vez

Comment: algunas base de datos definen el `?` para los parametros, es el caso de MySql, para Sql Server se usa el `@`. No es obligatorio si usas el AddWithValue() pero ojo que este toma el tipo de la variable que asignas, si un campo es numerico debes asignar una variable del tipo int. Usar  no esta forma de pasar parametros depende de que tanto control quieras al definir el parametro